# Splitting database table to frequently queried data + other data

Tags: mysql, database

Does splitting database table up to *most requested data* and *the rest of the data* gives considerable performance boost? I've spent last week or so watching very technical tutorials and conferences but it's still not clear to me how big part does columns count, columns position and rows count play in performance (**if whole table fits to memory/RAM**).

I've scetched 4 different options. What would be the pros and cons for each approach?

---

Some details:

- Mostly reads: at least 80% - emphasis is on performance
- 10 different categories - each with ~100K entries/rows
- 30 total values in each category
- 5 frequently queried values (used in both lists and single post views)
- 25 less frequently queried values (only in single post view)
- To specify: if I say *value*, I mean entity/database column

---

[image]

Comment: Why not just create big sample data and run some tests?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I figured that maybe somebody is good enough at this field and knows what he's talking about. This test would require huge preparations and maybe somebody else has the same question in future..

Comment: Performance tuning is no simple matter and simplification difficult; but it is usually more concerned with number of rows than it is with number of columns.  `select *` isn't encouraged and you should specify just the columns needed. Table design should follow rules of normalization.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Thanks for your comment. Im aware that you should start to denormalize only when you get performance problems but this is a huge project and I really don't want to mess it up. I then take it that 1M rows with 30 columns is acceptable if all queried columns are indexed? Im starting with shared host but I don't predict it to hit 1M overnight.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Just for additional information: I will have a front-end  filter that queries by up to 20 columns.. This makes me very edgy and Im afraid it might time out on shared host even when I don't have lots of rows at first.

Comment: Naturally indexing is vital to success but If you are already discussing denormalizing the data then you have made design decisions I am unlikely to change by a few words based on the thin amount of detail available. ps: If it is a huge as you believe it to be perhaps you should `also` be considering other dbms platforms (or variants e.g. percona/mariadb)

Comment: A million rows is not a huge table. And with 30 columns it isn't a wide table either. I see no reason for splitting this. Use one table and have the appropriate indexes. That's it. Don't make your data model more complicated then need be. (And if you *really* run into performance problems some day, then table partitioning should help: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html. But only do that when needed. Not now.)

Comment: @Used_By_Already Im actually already using MariaDB but I've always had an expression that it doesn't matter that much (at least compared to vanilla MySQL). i've looked into the differences between the two but I haven't found any _game-changer_ differences.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Thanks for the tip, I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one test case:

Create test data with 1M rows:

```sql
drop table if exists posts;
create table posts (
    id int not null primary key,
    summary varchar(255),
    post text
) as
    select seq as id
    , repeat(rand(1), 10) as summary
    , repeat(rand(1), 100) as post
    from seq_1_to_1000000
;

drop table if exists small_data;
create table small_data (
    id int not null primary key,
    summary varchar(255)
) as select p.id, p.summary from posts p
;
drop table if exists big_data;
create table big_data (
    id int not null primary key,
    post text
) as select p.id, p.post from posts p;

show table status where Name in('posts', 'small_data', 'big_data');

Name       | Engine | Row_format | Rows   | Avg_row_length | Data_length
big_data   | InnoDB | Compact    | 870341 |           2361 |  2055208960
posts      | InnoDB | Compact    | 838832 |           2627 |  2204106752
small_data | InnoDB | Compact    | 985832 |            229 |   226197504
```

So there are three tables.

- `posts` ~ 2.1 GB. contains all data (id, summary ~ 200 Bytes, post ~ 2000 Bytes).
- `small_data` ~ 215 MB. contains (id, summary)
- `big_data` ~ 1.9 GB. contains (id, post)

```sql
select p.id, p.summary
from posts p
order by id asc
limit 10
offset 500000
```

First run: 16.552 sec.
Second run: 16.723 sec.

```sql
select p.id, p.summary
from small_data p
order by id asc
limit 10
offset 500000
```

First run: 0.702 sec.
Second run: 0.093 sec.

You can see, there may be a huge difference. But it depends on your data and your queries. So you should do your own benchmarks.

Notes:

- Tested on 10.0.19-MariaDB.
- `seq_1_to_1000000` is a table with 1M sequence numbers. You will need to create it first or use MariaDBs Sequence plugin.